# str_replace is not replacing single quote properly

Tags: php, dom

I am having hard time replacing single quote through `str_replace`. Here is my code

```
function cleanstring($string) {

   $unwanted = array("’","'",";",".",":","’");
   echo "cleaned: ".str_replace($unwanted, "", $string);
}
```

Still output is

```
cleaned: Bob’s Burgers Season 1 Episode 1
cleaned: Bob's Burgers Season 2
```

Note: There are two types of quotes in above string.

Anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is perfectly working, can you provide the exact string you are passing?

Comment: `’` its not a single quotes

Comment: @Andrew, really? Why not for me :(

Comment: @MyWay here you can see it http://prntscr.com/941byz

Comment: Show us entire code, not the html generated one. That's what you have posted here

Comment: http://prntscr.com/941cjt

Comment: I have update my answer check it and let me know

Comment: @MShahzadKhan http://codepad.viper-7.com/17UaYX

Comment: @DeenadhayalanManoharan  It works when I pass string directly, but not when the code pass it. May be the code take string from another place has problem?

Comment: @Andrew please check above comment. I saw your demo, it works alone but not in my code.

Comment: you may also put a tag to the framework that you are using so people who is familar can help

Comment: I have update my answer with pass string using function call

Comment: I used "&#039" in replace function for single quote and it worked. Now I have to find unicode of the other character. I hope it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   <?php

$data="Bob’s Burgers Season 1 Episode 1";
$data1="Bob's Burgers Season 2";

    echo str_replace( array( "'","’" ),'',$data );
    echo "\n";
   echo str_replace( array( "'" ,"’" ),'',$data1 );


   echo "------------------------------------------";

   function cleanstring($string) {


   echo str_replace( array( "'" ,"’" ),'',$string);
}
 echo "\n";
cleanstring($data);
 echo "\n";
cleanstring($data1);

   ?>
```

Demo:https://eval.in/470891